# Kerberos Authentication with WCF not validating SPN

Tags: .net, wcf, spn

We have a WCF client and server authenticating with Kerberos Authentication.

It is our understanding that during Kerberos authentication, if the server specifies the endpoint’s SPN, it will only accept connections from clients who specify that SPN. It is also our understanding that the SPN specified must be registered under the account running the server application.

However, it appears that the authentication goes through regardless of what SPN the client uses in the endpoint identity. (As long as the SPN is registered in the domain)

For example:

1. User A registers the SPN “testspn/serveruser”.
2. User B can run the WCF server.
3. User C successfully connects to the WCF server with the SPN “testspn/serveruser” even though the SPN is not registered by user B.

Notes: We have verified that Kerberos authentication is in use by disabling NTLM authentication and traffic on the domain and setting up a behavior on the client to disable NTLM fallback.
In addition to this, we enabled System.Net tracing to see how the authentication was negotiated.
Questions:

1. Is our WCF configuration correct?
2. Is this by design?
3. Is this secure even though the SPN is not registered under the account running the service?
4. If not, how do we get it to validate that the SPN used is registered under the account running the service?

Comment: As far as I know, the client can pass the authentication through the SPN which has been registered in the domain. If SPN is not used for service authentication and other authentication is not used, there will be security problems. You can use UPN or another X.509 certificate for authentication. As a unique identifier, SPN must be unique on the server. More info can be found in [this link](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/06/04/kerberos-web-application-configuration/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply
We just NEED to be sure that is't supposed to work with just any spn that is registered in the domain, and not only the spn that the service account has registered.
Also, if that's the case, why does WCF bother with the SPN at all?

Comment: If a client accesses a service that is not registered with SPN under the running account and there is no other authentication, how do you verify that this is the service you want to access? I think the client predetermines the identity that the service should have before it authenticates it. When the actual service invocation is made, the client requires the service to provide the corresponding credentials. The client compares this credential with the identity determined by the implementation to determine that the service it is currently invoking is the one it wants to invoke.

Comment: Besides there are also X.509 certificates for service credentials,  which can be selected.